# Ansible - winrm or requests is not installed

Tags: linux, ansible

I was trying to connect the Windows 2016 machine from Ansible installed in my Fedora Virtual Box. I have installed python-pip as well as Pywinrm in my fedora machine.

When i tried to connect using following command

```
ansible all -i hosts -m win_ping -vvv
```

i am gettting following error

```
ansible 2.8.0
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
 python version = 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:45:16) [GCC 8.3.1 20190223 
(Red Hat 8.3.1-2)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's 
verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's 
verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's 
verify_file() method
Parsed /home/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
xx.xxx.xx.xxx | FAILED! => {
"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"
}
```

Below is the host file i used

```
[win]
xx.xxx.xx.xxx

[win:vars]
ansible_user=UserName.admin@test.com
ansibe_password=Password
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Answer (score 9):

I also searched this for long, finally this worked out for me

**Don't run this in virtual env, run it in the base environment**

```
pip install pywinrm
```

My python version: `3.7.3`

My pip version: `pip 19.3.1 from /Users/darcy/code/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

pywinrm version: `0.4.1`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I used @salmira's answer to check python with winrm and then I had to install **python2-winrm.noarch** to get Ansible to work.

```
yum install python2-winrm.noarch
```

And *voilà*:

```
$ ansible winhost -m win_ping
xxxxx | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run pip via desired python binary as a module `-m pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --ignore-installed pywinrm
```

Then test it:

1. test if python can find `winrm` module:

   ```
    import winrm

    s = winrm.Session('windows:5985', auth=('user', 'password'))
    r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])

    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.std_out.splitlines(True))
   ```
2. test if your Ansible has access to `winrm` module and your target:

   ```
    ansible windows -i inventory.ini -m win_ping
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me once I've run below:

```bash
pip install --user ansible pywinrm
```

Found the answer here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows